# Системное время на Си без time_t

Tags: c, время

На чистом Си.
В `time.h` есть тип данных `time_t`. Можно ли как-нибудь **без** использования этого типа получить системное время и поместить в переменную или массив. Нужно исключительно время ЧЧ:ММ:СС.

---

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В каком виде время вас устроит?

Comment: А чем не устраивает `time_t`?

Comment: На WinAPI легко такое пишется, без time_t.

Comment: @Cerbo
Это уже не особо важно, можно 3 переменных для каждого значения, можно в массив, можно с разделителями, можно без. Главное без типа `time_t`

Comment: @Harry
Не знаю как в полной мере работать с этим типом. Но если есть какие-то возможности, то можно и через `time_t`. А есть возможность преобразовать из этого типа в более простой?

Comment: «Не знаю как в полной мере работать с этим типом» — Ну так значит надо не без `time_t`, а просто научиться работать с `time_t` :)

Comment: Да по сути это же просто целое число! Вот и всё! Проще просто не бывает... А дальше используйте `localtime` или там `gmtime`, или функции для преобразования в строку - `asctime`, `ctime` или `strftime`...

Comment: @Harry с чего это оно просто целое?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Да, в стандарте это не указано :) Хотя в "C in a Nutshell", например, говорится "Тип аргумента, time_t, определен в заголовочном файле time.h, обычно как long или unsigned long." Словом, покажите реализацию, где time_t НЕ просто целое число...

Comment: @Harry это не научно, правильный подход: покажите, где в стандарте сказано, что это целое )). На практике, согласен, вряд ли разработчикам компиляторов взбредет такое в голову.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/471287/6266408

Answer (score 1):

Действительно неправильно отказываться от работы с этим типом данных. С ним достаточно удобно:

Необходиммые данные:

```
time_t r_time;
struct tm * time;
char buffer [100];
```

Проинициализировали:

```
r_time= time(0);
time= localtime (&r_time);
```

Воспользовались замечательной функцией strftime: (кст. - стандарт)

```
strftime (buffer, 100 ,"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M",time);
puts (buffer);
```

Кажется, это все.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int gettimeofday (struct timeval *restrict tp, void *restrict tzp);
```

Второй вариант:

```
int clock_gettime (clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *tp);
```

Comment: Разве это стандартные функции? Более того, разве `sys/time.h` - стандартный заголовочный файл?...

Comment: **Разве это стандартные функции?** Да, они определены в стандарте  ISO/IEC 9945

Comment: Это "The core of the Single UNIX Specification", но я не вижу, чтоб стояла метка Unix :) Тогда с тем же успехом можно советовать `GetLocalTime`...

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое **метка UNIX**. Я не понимаю, причём тут UNIX, Linux или Windows, TS писал о **чистом Си**.  Но я поимаю, что ISO - это "International Organization for Standardization". Т.е. документы, которые выпускаются этой организацией, называются СТАНДАРТЫ. Кстати, упомянутый мной стандарт официально действует на терртитории РФ.

Comment: Этот стандарт, в частности, задаёт "Definitions for system service functions and subroutines, language-specific system services for the C programming language". Т.е., то, что описано в данном стандарте, должно являться частью СТАНДАРТНОЙ реализации языка С в любой POSIX совместимой системе. Кстати, Микрософт неоднократно заявляла, что они добились полной POSIX совместимости...

Comment: Ну, теперь понятно, что ВЫ понимаете под СТАНДАРТОМ ЯЗЫКА... :( О метках - видите там, под вопросом, такие квадратики? В одном написано - "C", в другом - "время"? Там нет квадратика с надписью "UNIX", так что в вопросе интересует только язык C, а не его конкретная реализация для конкретной системы. Так понятно, что такое "метка UNIX"? А как называется ваш стандарт - я уже написал... Под стандартом C обычно понимают ISO/IEC 9899:2011, ISO/IEC 9899:1999 или ISO/IEC 9899:1990.

Comment: **интересует только язык C, а не его конкретная реализация для конкретной системы** - вот именно! С в системах Unix, Windows, IOs - это всё КОНКРЕТНЫЕ реализации. А POSIX - это всего лишь СТАНДАРТ, которому  должны следовать конкретные реализации. Ещё раз поясняю: если разработчики КОНКРЕТНОГО компилятора с языка С утверждают, что их реализация POSIX-совместима,  то они должны выполнять POSIX стандарт. Неужели это непонятно?! А разработчики всех (IMHO) существующих реализаций С декларируют эту совместимость.

Comment: Тот стандарт, на который Вы ссылаетесь, это МИНИМАЛЬНЫЕ требования, необходимые для того, что бы данный конкретный продукт был признан компилятором языка С.  В этом документе, в разделе 7.23  описан МИНИМАЛЬНЫЙ набор функций работы со временем. Там есть только одна(!!!) функция выбора системного времени: time_t time(time_t *timer); и ничего более не предусмотрено. Есть ещё clock_t clock(void); но это - время процессора, а не системное. Этот стандарт + стандарт POSIX и образуют реальные реализации компиляторов.

Comment: C тем же успехом можно написать собственные функции и обозвать их **стандартом языка**. Вести дальше эту бессмысленную дискуссию не буду, считайте для себя стандартом языка что угодно...

Comment: **можно написать собственные функции и обозвать их стандартом языка.** Никто не запрещает! Пишите - что угодно, называйте - как хотите... Вот только если Вы НЕ председатель соответствующего комитета ISO, деятельность эта вызовет только улыбку :-)

Comment: Спрятать `time_t tv_sec` внутрь неизвестной (а вдруг  ТС тоже страшно  станет?) структуры, а потом передавать в `localtime()` его адрес, но уже не задумываясь о  типе ... и уже не так страшно -- *хитрый совет, однако*.